# some programs not resolving hostnames

Tags: kernel, firefox, chromium, dns, hostname

Ubuntu 11.10, Kernel 3.0.0-20.34

Both Chromium and Firefox are stuck "waiting for www.whatever.com" to load until they time-out.

Both of these browsers can load these websites if I navigate to the IP address rather than the host-name.

Lynx (text mode) does not have this problem.

Ubuntu software centre can search for software without issue, but fails to install.

Using apt-get via the command line I am told that none of the packages "could be verified" but as long as I choose to continue, then I can install with no further issue. (guessing that's where software centre falls down)

I have now used apt-get to install a web browser I discovered on the software centre called 'Arora' which worked without any issues for the first few sites, and now stops loading at 10% every time.

Update manager will not update because "requires installation of untrusted packages". I am guessing its the "could not be verified" issue from command line apt-get.

`apt-get update`

Sticks at:

`5% [Waiting for headers]...`

So I am stuck with kernel version 3.0.0-20.34. I was hoping a kernel update might fix it.

`ping` works with host-names, without issue.

I believe these are all symptoms of the same problem. If they are not then I am sorry for asking multiple questions in one thread.

Any suggestions welcome, thanks for reading.

---

I forced grub to load and booted into the one previous kernel version I have (3.0.0-19). This did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since discovered that this is not ubuntu's fault at all, as I now have another machine with a different distro and the same symptoms.

It's something todo with my router's wireless connection. Specifically, the machines send http requests out and get nothing back. But only when connected wirelessly. Weird.